# How to test laravel model relationship in postman

Tags: php, postman, laravel-5.6

I am trying to test a relationship between Book and Rating models. User should be able to rate a book as long as they are signed in on the app. For some reason, my test on postman returns the error below

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'rating' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ratings` (`user_id`, `book_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 6, 2018-09-19 10:03:11, 2018-09-19 10:03:11))

Here's my **Rating Model**

```
class Rating extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'book_id', 'rating'];

/**
 * Rating/Book
 * A rating belongs to a book
 */
public function book()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}
}
```

**Book Model**

```
class Book extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'author'];

/**
 * Book/User relationship
 * A book belongs to only one user
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * Book/Rating relationship
 * A book has many ratings
 */
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class);
}
}
```

**RatingController**

```
public function store(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    // Allow only logged in users to rate books
    if ($request->user()->id) {

        $rating = Rating::create([
            'user_id'   => $request->user()->id,
            'book_id'   => $book->id,
        ],
        [
            'rating'    => $request->rating
        ]);

        return new Rating($rating);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error', 'Login to rate this book.'], 403);
    }
}
```

I obviously can't find where the problem lies or how to fix it and need some expert eyes and guide.

Comment: there's no need to call new Rating($rating) with the result of Rating::create. Rating::create returns an instance of Rating model that you just need to save ($rating->save()). Either that or return new Rating([array from Rating::create]);

Comment: @DanielProtopopov is this what you are suggesting `return new Rating($rating->save())` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request, Book $book)
{
    // Allow only logged in users to rate books
    if ($request->user()->id) {

        try {
            $rating = new Rating([
                'user_id'   => $request->user()->id,
                'book_id'   => $book->id,
                'rating'    => $request->rating
            ]);

            $rating->save();
            return $rating;
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            return response()->json(['error', 'Failed to create new user'], 403);
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error', 'Login to rate this book.'], 403);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your value for 'rating' is not being submitted. Why is rating in a separate array? You are trying to create one object to submit to the database. I would try:

```
if ($request->user()->id) {

    $rating = Rating::create([
        'user_id'   => $request->user()->id,
        'book_id'   => $book->id,
        'rating'    => $request->rating
     ])

 ...
```

A good test would be to create a default value in the database for a rating (e.g. 0), that way you can test to see which parts of your query are successful.

Comment: Tried that and got a totally different error `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/app/current/app/Http/Controllers/RatingController.php on line 33`

Answer (score 0):

its a sql error and dont related to postman, in Rating model you have a column called rating and this column cant be null when you insert a record in database, you have two solution, you can set a value for rating column in code when value is empty (such as 0 or null or empty string and ..) other solution is, you set a default value for rating columnin data base such as 0
in migration:

```
 $table->integer('rating')->default(0)
```

OR say database that filed can be null

```
$table->integer('rating')->nullable()
```

Comment: I understand defining a default value for it. In this case I am actually passing the rating value when testing in postman but SQL doesn't catch it

Comment: but in this query you miss rating column -> insert into ratings (user_id, book_id, updated_at, created_at) values (2, 6, 2018-09-19 10:03:11, 2018-09-19 10:03:11))

Comment: That's right, even though i pass it like so `{"rating": 5}` or `{"rating": "5"}` in post man i still get the same error. That's the problem

Comment: i think it a little wrong in you data format if its not problem,send you entire data to check with eachother